# Sending API calls in batches

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently trying to simulate half a million IoT devices to push payload to Azure IoT Hub using nodejs. Since node is multi-threaded in nature, its flooding iot hub with data and i am getting network errors.

I also tried async/await method but that is taking a lot of time to push data to IoT Hub.

Is there a way to only run 100 calls in parallel, wait for all of them to complete and then run the next 100 in node?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Javascript runtimes are single threaded.

Comment: The problem is not that its multithreaded but that its asynchronous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Build your batches as a nested array of `Promise`s, then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
on each batch in a loop that [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)s for each `Promise.all` to resolve.

```js
// This is a mock request function, could be a `request` call 
// or a database query; whatever it is, it MUST return a Promise.
const sendRequest = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('request sent')
      resolve()
    }, 1000)
  })
}

// 5 batches * 2 requests = 10 requests.
const batches = Array(5).fill(Array(2).fill(sendRequest))

;(async function() {
  for (const batch of batches) {
    try {
      console.log('-- sending batch --')
      await Promise.all(batch.map(f => f()))  
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
})()
```

Comment: How to pass a url to send rquest method. For example, I have urls list
var urls = [''https://example.com/A",''https://example.com/B", ''https://example.com/C"] and so on and I want to run these API in batches. But I am not getting how to pass the url?

Comment: Declare a parameter and send it as an argument, `const sendRequest = (url) {...}`, then in the loop `await Promise.all(batch.map(f => f('http://url.com')))`.

Comment: How to pass a dynamic url (with query params) which should be resolved from input array?

Comment: Does doing promise.all actually make it more efficient? as in the network overhead. Aren't we still sending out the same number of api requests?

Comment: @samplecode3300 Yes but they are sent out in parallel. We don't have to wait for the previous one to finish before sending the next one.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using lodash you can make it a bit easier by using [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk) which will divide an array into chunks of provided max size

So in your case you can use it like this

variable calls (array of 550 lets say)

```
const batchCalls = _.chunk(calls, 100);

for (const batchCall of batchCalls) {
  await Promise.all(batchCall.map(call => call())) // makes a hundred calls in series
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can readily use [bluebird Promise's map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) with concurrency option. This processes the max records as mentioned in the concurrency, before picking up the next batch.
example :

`Promise.map([], {concurrency : 100})`

Comment: Is there any way to use the `concurrency` option in just a standard `.all` call? What if we don't need to use `map`

Comment: @user2402616 `concurrency` option is provided by `bluebird` it's not an inherent js feature. It can't be used with `promise.all`

Answer (score 1):

`limited-request-queue` could be used to queue the request. There are options to set the Maximum number of connections at any given time. Below is the code we used to send 5 request every second. Also there will only be 5 request sent at any given time.

[limited-request-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/limited-request-queue)

```
/* 
   Request passed to Targer App (5 requests per seconds) 
   Get the response for each request and passed the response to Source App
   maxSockets: The maximum number of connections allowed at any given time. A value of 0 will prevent anything from going out. A value of Infinity will provide no concurrency limiting.
   maxSocketsPerHost:The maximum number of connections per host allowed at any given time. A value of 0 will prevent anything from going out. A value of Infinity will provide no per-host concurrency limiting.
   rateLimit: The number of milliseconds to wait before each maxSocketsPerHost
   */
var queue1 = new RequestQueue({'maxSockets': 5, 'maxSocketsPerHost': 5, 'rateLimit': 1000}, {
  item: function(input, done) {
      request(input.url, function(error, response) {
        input.res.send(response.body);
        done();
      });
  },
  end: function() {
      console.log("Queue  1 completed!");
  }
});

//To queue request - A for loop could be used to send multiple request
queue1.enqueue({'url': ''});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you can use the 'array' of items and the Promise.all() method (or in your case .allSettled() to just see the results of each call) and then process each one inside it like this:

```
function chunk (items, size) {  
  const chunks = [];
  items = [].concat(...items);

  while (items.length) { chunks.push(items.splice(0, size)); }

  return chunks;
}
async function ProcessDevice(device) {  
    // do your work here
}

// splice your items into chunks of 100, then process each chunk
// catching the result of each ProcessDevice in the chunk.map
// the results of the chunk are passed into the .then( )
// and you have a .catch( ) in case there's an error anywhere in the items
var jobArray = chunk(items,100); 
for (let i = 0; i < jobArray.length; i++) {
    Promise.allSettled(
        jobArray[i].map(ja => ProcessDevice(ja)))
    .then(function(results) { console.log("PromiseResults: " + results); })
    .catch((err) => { console.log("error: " + err); });
}
```