# NodeJS/knex How can I handle each item received when querying from the DB (records over 1 billion)

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

Let's say there are 1 billion+ records in the database, I need to send each record for verification.
If I use option 1, then the "memory leaks" (when using 1 million records, memory usage about 5Gb).
If I use option 2, then as expected I get an error about exceeding a 32 bit value (Timeout duration was set to 1. TimeoutOverflowWarning: 2164644000 does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer.)
*In addition, the request to check takes ~ 1-2 seconds

```
const url = require('url');
const http = require('http');

const knexOptions = {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'test0000'
        
    }
}
const knex = require('knex')(knexOptions);

knex.select('*').from('addresses')
.then(function(result) {
    /*
    //option 1
    result.forEach(function(record) {
        //console.log(record);
        makeRequest(record);
    });
    */
    
    //option 2
    result.forEach(function(record, index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            makeRequest(record);
        }, 3000 * (index + 1)); // or just index, depends on your needs
    });
    
    
});


function makeRequest(record) {
    let stringifyString = JSON.stringify(record);
    let parsedJSON =  JSON.parse(stringifyString);
    //console.log(parsedJSON.address);
    
    let _url = 'http://localhost/RestAPI.php?address=' + parsedJSON.address;
    let urlHost = url.parse(_url).host;
    let urlPath = url.parse(_url).path;

    var options = {
        host: urlHost,
        path: urlPath
    };

    callback = function(response) {
        let str = '';
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
            
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            //console.log(str);
            let parsedJSON =  JSON.parse(str);
            console.log(parsedJSON.valid);
            if (parsedJSON.valid) {
                //true received
                knex('addresses')
                .update({valid: true})
                .where('address', parsedJSON.address)
                .then(function(result) {
                    //console.log(result);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
                
            }
        });
    }

    let req = http.request(options, callback);
    req.end();
}
```

Can the community suggest a more elegant method/solution to my problem?
I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'd look into [batching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359384/sending-api-calls-in-batches/54359879) or chunking your requests. If you _have_ to do all of them, then do the requests in manageable parts.

Comment: Consider you have a billion of records. Even if verifying each one of them only takes 10ms, verifying all of them takes at least 10 million second, that's nearly three months ... Are you really sure you want to use node for that?

Comment: The most expensive part of your verification process is probably doing a http request for every single record. If you have control over your api, you should probably support batch requests where you can send a bunch of records to verify in one single request. That will save you a lot of time